# Load images over php-file with an one-time token (no javascript)

Tags: php, image, security, token

I'm thinking about a concept which loads images from a php-file with a token that is only valid once.

```
<img src="image.php?<?php echo 'img=title.jpeg&token=xyztokenxyz'; ?>" alt="token-image" />
```

So each time somebody loads this page he will get new token to load all the images on this site. And if someone tries to load an image with the same token he would get an error-message like "This token was already used"

My reason behind this is that I don't want people/bots to search through directories or try possible names of images.

Question: Is there possibly already a solution for this problem? Or is there any way something like this should be done in a certain way? Any suggestion are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look at .htaccess to prevent bot and other sites from scraping your images? On [this page you can find more info and generate the code](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/)